# How to make textbox change event to hold until length is 10

Tags: c#, events, textbox

What condition is satisfied when the amount of text in the text box is equal to 10? Currently, the event is firing on every keystroke.

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
           if(textbox1.Length == 10)
             {
             }

  }
```

Comment: Assuming you actually have `textbox1.Text.Length`, what is wrong with the event firing multiple times?  Your logic within the if statement is only running when Length is 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.TextLength==10)
        {
            //read DB and display stuff
            textBox1.Clear();
        }
    }
```

And just like other answerers I'm curious since your current code won't even compile. And if you write it in VS 2010/2012, the autocomplete should already offered the `TextLength`

Answer (score 3):

> I tried this and it is not working because this event is triggered each time I press a button on the keyboard.

That doesn't matter.  Your code wouldn't even compile as `TextBox` has no property `Length`, though it does have a `Text` property, which is a `string`, which has a `Length` property.

Be aware that there are other ways to change the text (i.e., pasting text in) which will fire `TextChanged` only once.  Also be careful as you may not want to trigger that code if the user presses the backspace or delete keys.  Performing actions in textboxes like this is often a bit trickier than one would expect.

Comment: I have an input of 10 numbers in sequence, it is a serial number. I want to read from database everytime I have a length = 10 and print a name of the product. I have focus on the textbox all the time so when I start writing new sequence I want to remove the old one.Thats it.

Comment: @denonth: Well, you have a start.  The code in the `if` will execute *every time* `textbox1.Text.Length` is `10`.  So, the next thing to do would be to clear out the textbox at some point, presumably if `Length > 10`.  You also need to account for the user pasting into the textbox and using the backspace/delete keys.  It doesn't sound great from a usability perspective. What's wrong with a submit button?  It would simplify the whole process quite a bit if it is acceptable in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You're 99% there, you're missing on thing, the `Text` property.

```
if(textbox1.Text.Length == 10)
{
}
```